# MultiLayer Neural Network

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Below is the code (taken from somewhere on the internet) that I am trying to use for Multilayer neural network.

```
import math
import random

BIAS = -1

"""
To view the structure of the Neural Network, type
print network_name
"""

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self, n_inputs ):
        self.n_inputs = n_inputs
        self.set_weights( [random.uniform(0,1) for x in range(0,n_inputs+1)] ) # +1 for bias weight

    def sum(self, inputs ):
        # Does not include the bias
        return sum(val*self.weights[i] for i,val in enumerate(inputs))

    def set_weights(self, weights ):
        self.weights = weights

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Weights: %s, Bias: %s' % ( str(self.weights[:-1]),str(self.weights[-1]) )

class NeuronLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_neurons, n_inputs):
        self.n_neurons = n_neurons
        self.neurons = [Neuron( n_inputs ) for _ in range(0,self.n_neurons)]

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Layer:\n\t'+'\n\t'.join([str(neuron) for neuron in self.neurons])+''

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_outputs, n_neurons_to_hl, n_hidden_layers):
        self.n_inputs = n_inputs
        self.n_outputs = n_outputs
        self.n_hidden_layers = n_hidden_layers
        self.n_neurons_to_hl = n_neurons_to_hl

        # Do not touch
        self._create_network()
        self._n_weights = None
        # end

    def _create_network(self):
        if self.n_hidden_layers>0:
            # create the first layer
            self.layers = [NeuronLayer( self.n_neurons_to_hl,self.n_inputs )]

            # create hidden layers
            self.layers += [NeuronLayer( self.n_neurons_to_hl,self.n_neurons_to_hl ) for _ in range(0,self.n_hidden_layers)]

            # hidden-to-output layer
            self.layers += [NeuronLayer( self.n_outputs,self.n_neurons_to_hl )]
        else:
            # If we don't require hidden layers
            self.layers = [NeuronLayer( self.n_outputs,self.n_inputs )]

    def get_weights(self):
        weights = []

        for layer in self.layers:
            for neuron in layer.neurons:
                weights += neuron.weights

        return weights

    @property
    def n_weights(self):
        if not self._n_weights:
            self._n_weights = 0
            for layer in self.layers:
                for neuron in layer.neurons:
                    self._n_weights += neuron.n_inputs+1 # +1 for bias weight
        return self._n_weights

    def set_weights(self, weights ):
        assert len(weights)==self.n_weights, "Incorrect amount of weights."

        stop = 0
        for layer in self.layers:
            for neuron in layer.neurons:
                start, stop = stop, stop+(neuron.n_inputs+1)
                neuron.set_weights( weights[start:stop] )
        return self

    def update(self, inputs ):
        assert len(inputs)==self.n_inputs, "Incorrect amount of inputs."

        for layer in self.layers:
            outputs = []
            for neuron in layer.neurons:
                tot = neuron.sum(inputs) + neuron.weights[-1]*BIAS
                outputs.append( self.sigmoid(tot) )
            inputs = outputs   
        return outputs

    def sigmoid(self, activation,response=1 ):
        # the activation function
        try:
            return 1/(1+math.e**(-activation/response))
        except OverflowError:
            return float("inf")

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([str(i+1)+' '+str(layer) for i,layer in enumerate(self.layers)])
```

My input is a text file containing multiple rows. Each row contains a data-point of dimension 16 (the first 16 elements of the row) and 17th element is the class to which the data point belongs.

**Input.txt**

```
1,3,2,2,1,10,2,2,1,9,2,9,1,6,2,8,2
2,1,3,2,2,8,7,7,5,7,6,8,2,8,3,8,4
4,6,6,5,5,8,8,3,5,7,8,7,5,10,4,6,2
6,9,6,11,6,7,7,8,5,9,8,8,4,9,7,9,5
1,1,2,2,1,7,7,8,5,7,6,7,2,8,7,9,1
3,8,5,6,4,10,6,3,6,11,4,7,3,8,2,9,3
4,7,5,5,5,8,6,6,7,6,6,6,2,8,7,10,1
6,10,9,8,8,11,6,2,4,9,4,6,9,6,2,8,11
```

The class is always in the range [1,11]
After learning the input, the expected output for each data-point should be its corresponding class (it may not be right always).
I am creating an object of NeuralNetwork class and then trying to use the update method.
But, I am not clear how to use it properly. Please guide me how to use it for the above input.

Answer (score 0):

This is my *open source* code

### How to

You have to initialize a new network object as: `network = NeuralNetwork(inputs, n_outputs, n_neurons_to_hl, n_hidden_layers)`.

```
inputs:          the number of input values                  (in your case: 16)
n_outputs:       the number of output values                 (in your case: 11)
n_neurons_to_hl: the number of neurons in each hidden layer
n_hidden_layers: the number of hidden layers
```

The `update( input_signals )` method is a forward calculation on the network - that is: this is the method you wish to use to classify an input instance.

Comment: I am using update method like: n = NeuralNetwork(16, 11, 2, 2)
n.update([4,8,6,6,5,10,6,2,6,11,3,7,3,8,3,10])
Please show me by example how to use the update method

Comment: That is the correct way to use it!:) The returned values will state which class the neural network has classified the current input instance as.  There is nothing more to show you. If you wish to train the network, you have to implement a learning algorithm eg: the backpropagation algorithm.